# How do I provide a UI to allow a user to specify an install path using WiX?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I need help with the question above. Also, how can I ensure that the application installs for all users using the machine? I haven't really used WiX before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I got the solution. I added the WixUIExtension dll as a reference and then used the following before the project closing tag:

```
<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLLOCATION" ></Property>
<UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir"/>
```

It works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

You're going to have to read the [tutorial](http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/).  There's just no way around it.  It should answer all your questions.

Comment: Was tempted to upvote, but "RTFM" is not a real answer. Better answer the question by quoting the documentation, which is a friendlier way to drive the point home.

Comment: I wasn't trying to be unfriendly.  Wix drives me a nuts.  Really, it was more of a lament.

Comment: Actually, for WiX v3, this is documented in the WiX.chm. @jeffamaphone, if you have suggestions how we can improve the WiX toolset, please let us know.